# Return ID in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web

I want to return userid against username and password

e.g.

1  abc  a

11 def  ab

when I enter abc in username textbox and a in password textbox then want to return 1 in label how to modify this code

```
 protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = @"Data Source=HOME\SQL;Initial Catalog=The_Coffe;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(query);
            con.Open();
            string b = "Select C_ID from Customer_Register where Email='" + TextBox1.Text + "'  AND password='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cam = new SqlCommand(b, con);
            cam.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox1.Text);
            cam.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);
            cam.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader dr = cam.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["Email"]);
                    TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(dr["password"]);
                     Session["UserName"] = TextBox1.Text;
                     Session["UserID"] = ID.Text;
                    //Response.Redirect("Fronpa.aspx");

                }




            }
            else
            {


                Label4.Visible = true;
                Label4.Text = "Incorrect Email or Password..";

            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks! See http://bobby-tables.com/ for an explanation and also see the examples there (for .NET) of how to properly use parameterised queries to protect your database from malicious inputs.

Comment: And do not store passwords unencrypted.

Comment: Anyway assuming you have a label called `Label1` then in your `while` loop, simply `Label1.Text = dr["UserID"].toString();` I think. Just the same as you assign the textbox values. Of course, even though you're using a while loop, I guess you really expect only one row to be returned? Usernames are forced to be unique I hope, despite the presence of an additional UserID field?

Comment: BTW in general, making your own authentication system like this is a bad idea and likely to be prone to errors. Better to use one of the built-in schemes provided by ASP.NET, such as Forms Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For Returning UserId in the above code, you can use

`Label1.Text = dr["id"].toString();` inside the `while (dr.Read())` code block